# addEventListener() not working for image in Firefox

Tags: javascript, image, firefox

I am creating an Image object in my javascript code. I want to attach a handler to this image for 'load' event. I am trying to do this using following code but the handler method is never called.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src='some url';
img.addEventListener('load', function(){
      //do something
}, false);
```

am I doing something wrong or is there any other way of doing this? 
I have already tried img.onload but it didnt work for me.

Comment: Try adding the event **before** setting the `src`. I don't think it'll fix it, but it's better practice to bind the event first. Are you sure the `"some url"` is good? The `load` event won't execute if the URL produces a bad response

Comment: @plalx Are you talking to me?

Comment: Your code works for me http://jsfiddle.net/vF7B2/. Wich browser are you using?

Comment: @plax I am using firefox version 19.0.2

Comment: @lan I am sure the url is correct.

Comment: @Ian, does the fiddle I posted work for you?

Comment: I did not want to confuse things but if it helps getting an answer I would specify that this code works for me in one machine and not in another one. Both are windows machine and I am using firefox in each.Both have the same code. The only difference I find important is that the machine in which it does not work is much faster and powerful than the other one. But I don't think it should be a problem.

Comment: @PratikPatel Do you save reference to `img` var somewhere? Show us a more real code. As is (if the variable is declared in global namespace), your code should work as long as event listener is added before the `src` attribute is set.

Comment: Ok, I got my code working now. @lan you were right , the problem was with the url. Actually the server was generating urls and it was configured to generate urls with "localhost" and not ip address of the machine. Because of this the code worked on the machine in which server was running and not on the other one.  Really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add event listener *before* assigning a value to the `src` attribute. If the image is already in browser's cache, `load` event may happen immediately after the `src` attribute is set.

Also, make sure you save a reference to the `Image` object to a variable that does not get destroyed automatically before image is downloaded. For example, if you instantiate an `Image` object inside a function and save a reference to it in a function-local variable, the object may be destroyed automatically right after execution of the function is finished. To prevent it, save a reference to the object in a global variable or in a property of a global object like this:

```js
window.example = {
    _images: []
};

example.preloadImage = function(url, callback) {
    var image = new Image;
    image.onload = callback;
    image.src    = url;

    // This prevents the image from destroying after the function is executed.
    example._images.push(image);
};

example.preloadImage('some-image.jpg', function() {
    alert('Image is loaded.');
});
```

Comment: @plalx That doesn't mean that when the `.src` property is set, the Javascript engine doesn't go and check the cache, and fire the `onload` event if it's cached. I'm not sure if it actually does that, but pointing out that JS is single threaded is irrelevant

Comment: @plalx Sorry, you don't understand. The event model has nothing to do with this. Unless you can prove the `load` event isn't fired immediately when an element is cached, you shouldn't act so big and mighty and 100% correct. It was an idea of ours and pointing out it's single threaded doesn't prove anything

Comment: @plalx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354865/image-onload-event-and-browser-cache

Comment: @Ian, I guess it depends on the implementation then, but in Chrome we can clearly see the event is fired asynchronously, event if the `img` is loaded from the cache. http://jsfiddle.net/vF7B2/1/

Comment: @MaratTanalin, if you edit the answer I will be able to remove my downvote.

Comment: @plalx I have no idea what exact edit are you talking about. (I don't care about downvotes BTW.)

Comment: @MaratTanalin, The vote is locked-in unless the answer gets edited.

Comment: @MaratTanalin I was saving the reference of my image object like you said. The problem was with url (see my comment above).  Thanks for your help.