# Does the order of either onload or addEventListener and setting an image's src actually matter?

Tags: javascript, dom

I've held it as an "absolute truth" for a long time that doing:

```js
let img = new Image();
img.src = '... some url ...'
img.onload = function() { console.log('onload') }
```

was *wrong*, because the `.onload` handler might not be called. Same thing for attaching a handler using `.addEventListener('load', function() ... )` after setting `.src`: it might not work. (see this [example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15881868) stating this: "... Add event listener before assigning a value to the src attribute ...")

---

Context for this question: I've found an example of setting `.src` before calling `.addEventListener` in the popular p5.js library, specifically [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/main/src/dom/dom.js#L415-L417). I would like to fix this and submit a PR. However, I would also like to create a unit test that *fails* with the current code (setting `.src =` before calling `.addEventListener`) and *passes* with my fix.

However! I haven't been able to actually see under which circumstances setting `.src` before actually fails...!

---

Here is some code to demonstrate what I mean:

```js
(function f() {
  let i = new Image();
  i.src = '//placekitten.com/10/10';
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(i);
  
  let out = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) { out *= i * 100 - out * 2; } // just to delay

  i.onload = function() { console.log('onload') }
  i.addEventListener('load', function() { console.log('load event') });
})();
```

The 1000000000-iteration loop takes a few seconds to complete, as I'm trying to get the `Image` element to be added to the DOM and the image URL to be loaded early enough that the `.onload` and `.addEventListener` handlers would fail... But they work!

I tried with a very short data URL instead of placekitten.com, same result. I tried loading the placekitten.com and the data URL images before running my test code (to make sure those images are cached), but that doesn't work either.

The only way I can get the `.onload` and `.addEventListener` handlers to not be called is to wrap them in a `setTimeout`...

---

Is JavaScript's single-threadneness invalidating the "truth" that `.src` should always be set after setting event listeners? Or is this a change that happened in modern browsers, and it used to be true in older browsers that setting `.src` before attaching listeners would sometimes fail? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order doesn't matter. The `load` event is always fired asynchronously (queued on the event loop by [the loading algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#reacting-to-environment-changes)), after the synchronous execution has completed, and will evaluate which event listeners are installed and need to be executed only then.

Given the [answer that you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15881868/1048572) and especially [image.onload event and browser cache](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12354865/1048572) / [jQuery callback on image load (even when the image is cached)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3877027/1048572), it appears older browsers might have fired the event synchronously (or not at all) if the image was loaded from the cache.

Comment: Fascinating, thanks a lot. I feel like I might be holding on to a truth from the IE9 days. I'm really curious what browsers did do it syncronously. I tried the code from my question in IE11 and the src/onload order did not matter there either. EDIT: I deleted a previous comment where I asked whether @Bergi thought it might be a case of "cargo cult" -- just to put the answer below in context.

Comment: @GregSadetsky I would say yes, it's a cargo cult at least for dom and other native events. However, I don't want to rule out older browsers misbehaving (even if only in edge cases), and especially non-native pub/sub APIs might have bad implementations that expose this problem (known as [releasing zalgo](https://blog.izs.me/2013/08/designing-apis-for-asynchrony)). So I guess it still might be a good practice in general.