# Image onLoad event in isomorphic/universal react - register event after image is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

In isomorphic rendered page image can be downloaded before main `script.js` file. So image can be already loaded before `react` register `onLoad` event - never trigger this event.

`script.js`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleImageLoaded = this.handleImageLoaded.bind(this);
}

handleImageLoaded() {
    console.log('image loaded');
} 

render() {
    return (
        <img src='image.jpg' onLoad={this.handleImageLoaded} />
    );
}
```

---

#### Scenario 1 - `image.jpg` is bigger than `script.js`

[image: image.jpg is bigger than script.js]

In this scenario everything is working fine. Event is registered before image is finally loaded so in console is `image loaded` message.

---

#### Scenario 2 - `image.jpg` is smaller than `script.js`

[image: image.jpg is smaller than script.js]

This scenario you can see problem described at the beginning of post. `onLoad` event is not triggered.

---

#### Question

What can I do in order to trigger `onLoad` event in **scenario 2**?

---

#### EDIT: Soviut answer implementation

To detect if image is ready on render you should check `complete` property on pure javascript `img` object:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { loaded: false };
    this.handleImageLoaded = this.handleImageLoaded.bind(this);
    this.image = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount() {
    const img = this.image.current;
    if (img && img.complete) {
        this.handleImageLoaded();
    }
}

handleImageLoaded() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
        console.log('image loaded');
        this.setState({ loaded: true });
    }
} 

render() {
    return (
        <img src='image.jpg' ref={this.image} onLoad={this.handleImageLoaded} />
    );
}
```

Comment: How will the browser know that it need to fetch an image unless the script got loaded into the DOM?

Comment: It's isomorphic app. I render this html with image element on backend with `node`.

Comment: This doesn't take care of handling the image somehow before react loads?

Comment: @pailhead Nope, if image is faster than react event only fire on `componentDidMount`

Comment: I too couldn't understand why the hell the onload never fired... never even thought of the possibility that the image, which was rendered through the jsx of the script, the script that's supposed to load first, could load after the image itself until I remembered that I was building static html files with gatsby...

Comment: @eballeste also using Gatsby - were you able to pass a ref to the inner <img> from the Gatsby Image component?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could check the `complete` property on the image before applying the `onload` event.

```
if (!img.complete) {
    // add onload listener here
}
```

Comment: It looks promising. Can you update answer with placing this `if (!img.complete)` in my `script.js`?

Comment: I'd rather keep the example simple. Just wrap `this.handleImageLoaded = this.handleImageLoaded.bind(this);` in the if statement, fetching the img tag first, of course.

Answer (score 25):

This is all a bit tidier with Hooks:

```
const useImageLoaded = () => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
  const ref = useRef()

  const onLoad = () => {
    setLoaded(true)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current && ref.current.complete) {
      onLoad()
    }
  })

  return [ref, loaded, onLoad]
}

const SomeComponent = ({ src }) => {
  const [ref, loaded, onLoad] = useImageLoaded()

  return (
    <div>
      <img ref={ref} onLoad={onLoad} src={src} alt="" />
      {loaded && <h1>Loaded!</h1>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Another way is to use ref and cover those both scenarios:

```
<img
  ref={(input) => {
    // onLoad replacement for SSR
    if (!input) { return; }
    const img = input;

    const updateFunc = () => {
      this.setState({ loaded: true });
    };
    img.onload = updateFunc;
    if (img.complete) {
      updateFunc();
    }
  }}
  src={imgSrc}
  alt={imgAlt}
/>
```

Comment: remember to add `img.onload = null` at the end of the function, to avoid a setting state on unmounted component

Answer (score 10):

img.complete is true even when the src load fails.

> complete - Returns a Boolean that is true if the browser has finished fetching the image, **whether successful or not**. It also shows true, if the image has no src value.

1. Use naturalWidth as determinant whether the img load was successfull or not

```
    state = {
        isLoading: true,
        hasError: false,
    }

    myRef = React.createRef();

    componentDidMount() {
        const img = this.myRef.current;

        if (img && img.complete) {
            if (img.naturalWidth === 0) {
                this.handleOnError();
            } else {
                this.handleImageLoaded();
            }
        }
    }

    handleImageLoaded = () => {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        }
    }

    handleOnError = () => {
        this.setState({ hasError: true });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <img
                src={src}
                alt={alt}
                ref={this.myRef}
                onError={this.handleOnError}
                onLoad={this.handleOnLoad}
            />
        );
    }
```

2. Another way is to add "check" image in componentDidMount a set eventHandler to it and let the check image be the one to handle eventListeners

```
componentDidMount() {
   const testImg = new Image();
   testImg.onerror = this.handleOnError;
   testImg.onload = this.handleImageLoaded;
   testImg.src = this.props.src; // important to set eventlisteners before src
}
```

Comment: Note that for Option 1 (`naturalWidth`) there is a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1607081) regarding svg's on Firefox, which causes that the naturalWidth is always 0, thus triggering the handleOnError method even though it could have been successful. I had to find out myself after 2 hours of debugging..

Answer (score -3):

```
<img
    src={this.props.imageUrl}
    onLoad={this.handleImageLoaded.bind(this)}
    onError={this.handleImageErrored.bind(this)}
/>
```

Comment: I will not work if the image loads faster than this function register. I've explained in question why this code will not work.

Comment: @Everettss i believe that script will be executed first and then render will be called, so image will be added to dom after that and onload will always come after render method.
That being the reason, i dont think you need more code than this.

Comment: @Everettss please read the comment by jfriend00 in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12355031/5895990)

Comment: @AmitDhaka It will be nice if you include an explanation in answer, not only the code. I believe your false assumptions came from misunderstanding how [isomorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064707/what-does-an-isomorphic-react-mean) rendering works. I'm using this `.complete` method on my [blog](https://michaljanaszek.com/) - check the page source and you will see HTML with `<img />` tag before any react script is ready.