# Firefox is not displaying image in drag and drop ghost preview

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to display ghost element instead of default browser preview for drag and drop. The problem is that in firefox image inside ghost element is not displayed while dragging. But if I drop it, and drag again the image *is* displayed.

So I think that this might be some sort of cache-related problem. But I can't see how I can pre-cache image in this case.

Here's the code:

//html:

```
<div class="parent container">
<img class="element" src="http://www.thekrausemouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Sample.jpg" draggable="true" />
</div>
```

//js:

```
document.querySelector(".element").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.width = '100px';
    div.style.height = '100px';
    div.style.position = 'fixed';
    div.style.top = '-1000000px';
    div.style.left = '-1000000px';
    div.style.border = '2px solid red';

    img.src = "http://www.thekrausemouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Sample.jpg";
    img.style.width = '100px';
    img.style.height = '100px';
    div.appendChild(img);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'test');
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(div, 0, 0);
}, false);
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/etseq5cg/5/

Steps to reproduce:

1) open fiddle/run snippet

2) try to drag sample image

Actual: you'll see an empty square with red border

Expected: square with image inside.

To reproduce it again you need to force-reload the page(ctrl+f5). That's why I think this is cache-ralated issue.

Note: I know that I should remove ghost element from DOM in dragend handler, but this is not important here.

***Update:***

1) the actual use-case includes view with big amount of images(~500), so it's not an option to pre-cache images via js.

2) For the ones who couldn't reproduce the issue, here's the screenshot: at first you see preview after hard reload(ctrl+f5), and then the second dragging attempt. Please note that no http requests are seen in network tab in web inspector in both cases. [image: screenshot]

Comment: The problem you are having is your image is being loaded after the div is appended to your body. You can use image `onload` to wait for the image to load, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354865/image-onload-event-and-browser-cache. You could instead create the element before the user drags the element (on page load) so you shouldn't have to deal with waiting for the image to load.

Comment: @toggy-tog-togs I can't wait for image onload event because this is async operation and calling 'setDragImage' is sync. So if I call 'setDragImage' inside 'onload' callback it wont do anything.

And as you can see the image itself is already added to the DOM(I use same image for preview and dnd ghost).

Comment: I tried the jsfiddle in Firefox. When I drag the "Sample" image, I see the "Sample" ghost image.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I've added 'Update' section with screenshots of what i'm getting.

Answer (score 7):

I cannot see the problem when I run [your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etseq5cg/5/) in Firefox 53 (on Windows 7). The ghost image and the dragged image have the same URL and the ghost image is always displayed when dragging. However, I can reproduce the problem with a ghost image that has a different URL.

You could add a hidden `img` control to preload the ghost image. Something like this:

```
<div class="parent container">
    <img class="element" draggable="true" src="http://the.element.image" />
    <img class="imgGhost" src="http://the.ghost.image" />
</div>
```

According to my tests, these settings prevent the image preload in Firefox:

- Hiding the element with `display: none`
- Setting a null size (`width: 0px` or `height: 0px`)
- Moving it outside of the viewport (e.g. `left: -10000px`)

I also did not have much success with [link prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ). However, `visibility: hidden` seems to work. The style of the hidden image element could be defined as:

```
.imgGhost {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The method can be tested for two draggable images in [**this jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/40pvw0dg/13/). In the `dragstart` event handler, the image URL is retrieved from the hidden element:

```
img.src = this.parentNode.querySelector(".imgGhost").src;
```

but it could be hard coded. If you prefer, you could set the `src` attribute of the hidden image dynamically when the page is loaded. When testing in the jsfiddle, you can change the ghost image names (e.g. 225x225) before running it again, to make sure that the image was not cached.

---

According to your comment, preloading the image is not an option. And you are using the same image URL for the dragging ghost image. In that case, you could check [this page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-problems-images-not-show) to see if any option is preventing the reload of the image.

You could also force a repaint of the layout after adding the `div` control to the `body` in the `dragstart` event handler. This can be achieved by calling `div.offsetHeight`:

```
div.appendChild(img);
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.offsetHeight; // Force repaint
```

Comment: Was able to reproduce issue described at OP at firefox 53 at *nix.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. I've added 'Update' section for the question with example of what I'm getting. Unfortunately pre-caching the image is not an option for me.

Comment: If the screen shots are obtained with [your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etseq5cg/5/), we must have different configurations. What OS are you using? And which version of Firefox? Since the image is already displayed, it should be available. Do you have the RealPlayer plugin (apparently, it can [cause trouble when reloading images](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-problems-images-not-show#w_images-load-the-first-time-but-not-later))?

Comment: @Rasalom - I added another suggestion to my answer: force a repaint after adding the `div` element to the layout.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but none of the options worked for me. I guess I'll have to write good old js drag preview.

Comment: Which OS and which version of Firefox are you using? The problem may be specific to that combination.

Answer (score 2):

At `css` set `.parent` pseudo class `:hover` and `.element` `background` to `url("/path/to/image")` to fetch image at `:hover` of `<img class="element" src="http://www.thekrausemouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Sample.jpg" draggable="true" />` parent element. At `dragstart` event set `div` `.className` to `"element"`.

```css
.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url("http://www.thekrausemouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Sample.jpg");
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  
}

.parent:hover {
  background: url("http://www.thekrausemouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Sample.jpg");
  background-size: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent container">

  <img class="element" src="http://www.thekrausemouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Sample.jpg" draggable="true" />

</div>
    <script>
    function handleImage(e) {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.style.width = '100px';
      div.style.height = '100px';
      div.style.position = 'fixed';
      div.style.top = '-1000000px';
      div.style.left = '-1000000px';
      div.style.border = '2px solid red';
      div.className = "element";
      document.body.appendChild(div);
      e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'test');
      e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(div, 0, 0);
    }
 document.querySelector(".element")
 .addEventListener("dragstart", handleImage, false);
  </script>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/etseq5cg/7/