# Scroll Bottom Angularjs Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scroll

I am working on chat app, and the problem seems to be that directive for scroll bottom, to the last item in ng-repeat is not working properly when there are images in messages.
So it just doesn't scroll all the way bottom.
I think the reason is that directive scrolls before the image is fully loaded.

```
                  // Scroll to bottom directive
                    .directive('schrollBottom', function ($timeout) {
                      return {
                        scope: {
                          schrollBottom: "="
                        },
                        link: function (scope, element) {
                          scope.$watchCollection('schrollBottom', function (newValue) {
                            if (newValue)
                            {
                             $timeout(function() { 

                          $(element[0]).scrollTop($(element)[0].scrollHeight);
                         }, 0, false);



                            }
                          });
                        }
                      }
                    })
```

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354865/image-onload-event-and-browser-cache) to see how to wait for an image to load before doing something. You can add a class to all images and wait for all images with that class to load before scrolling.

Comment: @Lansana, Thanks is there is a way to have things in one directive, one is watch the collection and second condition if image loaded?

Comment: I would keep what logic you have, and put it inside of an `img.onload` callback handler. Then any scrolling to the bottom will only occur once all images have loaded.

Comment: @Lansana, thank you. you can mark as answer i will accept it.

Comment: Answered :) glad I could help!

Comment: @Lansana, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354865/image-onload-event-and-browser-cache) to see how to wait for an image to load before doing something. You can add a class to all images and wait for all images with that class to load before scrolling.

I would keep what logic you have, and put it inside of an `img.onload` callback handler. Then any scrolling to the bottom will only occur once all images have loaded.