# How to fade in images when loaded with Vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I created this component that fades in an image once it is loaded to the client. I would think there is a more Vue-like way to solve this, like using Vue events, but could not find it. What is the Vue way to detect when an image is loaded?

https://codepen.io/kslstn/pen/ooaPGW

```js
Vue.component('imageThatFadesInOnLoad',{

  data: function(){
    return {
      src: 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
      loaded: false,
    }
  },

  mounted: function () {
    var image = new Image()
    var that =  this
    this.loaded = image.addEventListener('load', function(){that.onLoaded()}) // This is the key part: it is basically vanilla JS
    image.src = this.src
  },

  methods:{
    onLoaded(){
      this.loaded = true
    }
  },

  template: `
    <div class="wrapper">
      <transition name="fade">
        <img class="icon" v-bind:src="src" v-if="loaded">&nbsp;
      </transition>
   </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#wrapper'
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  background: slategrey;
}
.fade-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
}
.fade-enter-to{
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade-enter{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.4/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
<image-that-fades-in-on-load></image-that-fades-in-on-load>
</div>
```

Comment: `@load="onLoaded"`? (or `v-on:load="onLoaded"`) https://jsfiddle.net/vcL986Lx/

Comment: Somehow that doesn't work in a template: https://codepen.io/kslstn/pen/dZgqNW

I can't find documentation on v-on:load, but maybe it is called when the Vue app starts to load? At that time the template wouldn't be done rendering yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`v-on:`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) (or `@` shorthand) syntax for binding to any DOM event. In your case the `load` event, which is triggered when the image is loaded.

Because you are loading the image "the DOM way" you can't use `v-if` because then Vue will not render the element (but you need it to, so the image src is fetched). Instead you can use [`v-show`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show), which will render but hide the element.

```js
Vue.component('imageThatFadesInOnLoad', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      src: 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
      loaded: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onLoaded() {
      this.loaded = true;
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div class="wrapper">
      <transition name="fade">
        <img class="icon" v-bind:src="src" v-on:load="onLoaded" v-show="loaded">&nbsp;
      </transition>
   </div>
  `
});

new Vue({
  el: '#wrapper'
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  background: slategrey;
}

.fade-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
}

.fade-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.4/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <image-that-fades-in-on-load></image-that-fades-in-on-load>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you. I've updated my previously broken codepen: https://codepen.io/kslstn/pen/dZgqNW

I've removed mounted and methods, as they are no longer necessary this way!

Comment: I think this only works on first load. At least in my case. Because the @load event is not triggered if the image is already cached. Without the @load event `this.loaded` will never be set to true hiding my image forever... – I have not found a proper solution so far though. – but I also see that your codepen is working... . My code does not ‍♂️

Comment: @Merc huh, never heard about this, but it looks legit. You may want to check for vanilla solutions in order to tweak Vue's code, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354865/image-onload-event-and-browser-cache or http://mikefowler.me/journal/2014/04/22/cached-images-load-event | The promising solution looks like the one along "set event listener then src"

Comment: thanks @yuriy636. I think I already found and read all your three pages. None of them seemed to solve my problem. (Although I have to say, that maybe I did not fully commit to trying out everything,...) .

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a slightly different approach to the answers above, using a native CSS solution instead of the Vue `<Transition>` way.

In the code below, we just add a `class` to the `<img>` when it loads triggering a transition.

```
<template>
  <img
    :class="imgIsLoaded ? 'show' : ''"
    src="myImg.jpg"
    loading="lazy"
    @load="imgLoadedMethod"
  >
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      imgIsLoaded: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    imgLoadedMethod () {
      this.imgIsLoaded = true
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 3s;
}

img.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

Comment: how would this work with multiple images or elements from a loop? Trying to run a method on the element which returns a landscape or portrait class.

Comment: @v3nt The code in the answer could be implemented as a component. You could then loop that component in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

To make transitions work when you dynamically replace cached images, you need to add a unique key. Otherwise vue's compiler will only replace the content of the element for efficiency and the transition will not be triggered.

```html
<template>
  <div :style="{width: width+'px', height: height+'px'}">
    <transition name="fade">
      <img
        v-show="loaded"
        @load="onImageLoad"
        :src="src"
        :alt="alt"
        :width="width"
        :height="height"
        :key="src"
      />
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ["src", "width", "height", "alt"],
  data() {
    return {
      loaded: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onImageLoad() {
      this.loaded = true;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    src: {
      handler() {
        this.loaded = false;
      },
      immediate: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.fade-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.fade-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```