# getBoundingClientRect() returns 0 for width and height of image

Tags: javascript, getboundingclientrect

Ho do I use getBoundingClientRect() to determine the width and height of image

```js
function popUp() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.id = "TT";
  img.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  var img = document.getElementById("TT");
  console.log(img)
  var dims = img.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(dims)
}
popUp();
```

Comment: image has not loaded yet when you are getting the values, try to move your part of `dims` variable inside a `img.onload = function(){...}`

Comment: how do I wait until it's loaded?

Comment: @DCR I have added a snippet for waiting for the loading of image.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the image is not loaded at the time of `log`. You need to `console.log` inside `onload` function

```js
function popUp() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.id="TT";
  img.src="https://picsum.photos/200/300";    
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  img.onload = function(){
    var img = document.getElementById("TT");
    var dims = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(dims)
  }
}
popUp();
```

If you want the function to await for further execution of the function until the image is loaded you can create a promise and then await for it. But this will make the structure of the code asynchronous

```js
async function popUp() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.id="TT";
  img.src="https://picsum.photos/200/300";    
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  const imageLoaded = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    img.onload = function(){
      var img = document.getElementById("TT");
      var dims = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      res(dims)
    }
  });
  
  const data = await imageLoaded;
  console.log(data)
 
}
popUp();
```

Comment: isn't better to set the `onload` listener before setting `src` of the dynamically created image? As stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12355031/8732818