# How to execute svg.setAttribute("width", svg.getBBox().width); on the server-side?

Tags: github, svg, content-security-policy

I am trying to deliver an SVG response with the help of NodeJS. This SVG has a small inline JavaScript code that dynamically calculates the width of the SVG. Everything works when the APIs are called directly using the browser. But when I use these APIs in GitHub's readme (to server SVGs in readmes) it's not allowing me to run this inline JavaScript code stored in SVG.

So when I asked this [why custom headers for content-security-policy not working on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65433947/why-custom-headers-for-content-security-policy-not-working-on-github) question, I got to know that github doesn't allow any inline JS, and we can't override Github's Content-Security-Policy to execute JS stored in SVGs.

So now I thought of executing the inline JavaScript on the server-side to calculate the SVG width and embed that in SVG. But the problem is how to execute this `svg.setAttribute("width", svg.getBBox().width);` at server side. As these SVGs are `Template Literals` on the server-side.

*Questions:*

> Is there a way to calculate the width of SVG without rendering it on the server-side? 
> `OR` 
> Do I have to create a virtual DOM on the server-side to load the SVG in that DOM and then calculate the width? 
> `OR` 
> Is there a way to do this without JavaScript?

Can anyone help me out on how to get the dynamic width of SVG on the server-side?

Comment: You either need a complete rendering engine (a headless browser) server-side or a custom library that will do the job for you. There are libs on npm, but I have never looked into them, so I can't tell you anything about their quality.

Comment: You are probably going to have to use something like [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer).  Or write a standalone program with something like [Batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/), that you can call from Node.