# Using JS is it possible to detect when new Image().src has loaded the image it references into memory?

Tags: javascript

**Background:** I'm trying to get the dimensions of an image.

This block successfully creates a new image and assigns it a graphic.  Unfortunately this doesn't happen instantly.  When I attempt to get height with `naturalHeight` it returns 0.

```
let myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = 'images/example.png';

let dimension = myImage.naturalHeight;
alert(dimension); // 0
```

However if I delay this action with `setTimeout()` it gives the browser time to load it into memory and it returns the height.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    let dimension = myImage.naturalHeight;
    alert(dimension); // 479
}, 1000);
```

**Question:** Is there a way to detect if the image reference has been fully loaded into memory?  This way I can grab `naturalHeight` after I know the referenced image is loaded.

Comment: `myImage.addEventListener('load', function() { /* your code here */ })`

Comment: @connexo Holy smokes I'm embarrassed.  I didn't realize it worked the same on variables as it did on elements.

Comment: Your variable holds a reference to an element, so why would it be any different?

Comment: @connexo Well it doesn't always have to make sense but you're right that makes perfect sense.  And it 100% worked.

Comment: Well think about it, how are you ever calling `addEventListener` on anything other than a reference to an element? Be it one stored in a variable, or one available at the moment of execution only like `document.createElement('img').addEventListener(...)`.

Comment: @connexo I understand `.addEventListener()` what I didn't realize was that `new Image()` was creating an image element.  I just started using it today and thought it was some sort of image constructor, I wasn't really sure what for.  Once I learned it was making an image element your answer made perfect sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen to the `onload` event for the element.

```
let myImage = new Image();

// Be sure to add the event listener before
// changing the image's source attribute.
myImage.onload = function() {
  let dimension = myImage.naturalHeight;
  alert(dimension);
};

myImage.src = 'images/example.png';
```

More information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12355031/14956277).