# Canvas context.toDataUrl() returning a "data:"

Tags: typescript, image, canvas, base64, todataurl

I'm trying to create a function that converts an image url to a base64 string. The problem is that the return value of the toDataUrl function is "data:"

```
`export const getBase64FromImageUrl = (url: string): string => {
  const img = new Image()
  img.src = url
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.width = img.width
  canvas.height = img.height
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

  if (!ctx) return ''

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
  return canvas.toDataURL()
}`
```

and then I call this function passing a url from a jpg image store in a s3 bucket. The bucket allows cross origin so I think that's not the problem.

Comment: in your code there is no guarantee the image has been loaded by the time you call `drawImage` look at others that have asked similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354865/image-onload-event-and-browser-cache