# How to track image loading on the site?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, captcha

I'm writing an automatic registration on a website and it needs to pass captcha. The problem is that the captcha picture is not always loaded, sometimes you need to wait 10-20 seconds for it to load, and you need to register instantly after the captcha is loaded, so that you have time. I do everything on Selenium Python, to send captcha to the service - I make a screenshot of the whole page with captcha, the picture of captcha can not load, when you go to its url, there is an empty image. When the registration opens, the captcha is already there in the code, but the picture just doesn't load immediately.

Comment: Why can't you use Selenium to explicitly wait for the specific element to be loaded?

Comment: maybe you need event `onload` in `JavaScript` - (example question [javascript - image.onload event and browser cache - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354865/image-onload-event-and-browser-cache)). OR maybe you should get current screenshot and compare with screenshot without empty image - to see if something changed. Maybe you could use Python module `cv` for `Computer Vision`. Other idea: if image after loading moves objects on page then you could check position of other elements, and this may need `JavaScript`