# Google Map render events, can they be watched?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to watch for the completion of the rendering of Google map tiles?

Related to this, is there a way to test whether or not all map tiles were successfully rendered?

This is based on an unresolved issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347774/why-are-not-all-google-map-tiles-rendered-on-the-initial-load-of-an-angularjs-ap).

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341769/google-maps-v3-how-to-tell-when-an-imagemaptype-overlays-tiles-are-finished-lo) for a part of your question > is there a way to test whether or not all map tiles were successfully
> rendered?

Answer (score 4):

Listen for the `tilesloaded` event, e.g.

```
google.maps.event.addListener( 'tilesloaded', function() {
    // tiles have been loaded
});
```

I don't think there is any method in the API to ask whether the tiles have been loaded, but you can set a flag in your event listener.

Comment: Thank you Michael, your answer is useful and perhaps can wrap the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7355063/913295) mentioned by varun.

Comment: Awesome. Used this and added in a check to make sure it only fires once, then forced my map to center when the event fires. I had to add my map object before the 'tilesloaded' parameter though, e.g. `addListener(myMap, 'tilesloaded', function()...`